# Displaying user details on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

First of all I am new to ASP.NET and C#. I built a system that has a login control, and I have a SQL database in the backend.

So here is my question:

I want to have an interface that displays account details to the currently logged in user. How should I approach this?

Comment: What do you mead by "information"? this is really broad.

Comment: Why exactly did you create the login control yourself, instead of using the provided controls? Also agree with DavRob60 - you really need to provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try to expand your question on what you're trying to do if possible.

However, you should store details about a user under the `Profile` variables. Avoid Session variables for storing any customer details. If you need to reference their username to pull details, use the provided fields such as `User.Identity.Name`.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Also you can use the `LoginView` control to only display details to users that have logged in. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx

A general overview of this usage can be seen at http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb.

You can display the Profile variables inside of the LoginView or inside of a page that is protected by the Membership.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display User information ,like Username ,Age ,Name ,Surname etc. 
Than gather these information's from DataBase and store them in [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) and display these Information's where ever you want .
You can retrieve these Information's while User is Logged in ,and you can display in any Page you want while .
Use any Object HTML you wish to Print these with `Respond.WriteLine();`

Comment: -1 because he's asking about Asp.Net, not ASP, which is what your example website is showing. I'd like to give you another -1 if I could since your example site is w3schools.com - the absolute worst site to reference for anything code related on the internet.